# laravel 8 storage url not working storage::url()

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, local-storage, laravel-8

`Storage::url($this->productImage)`
This returns me in this form `<< storage / 1638955495_1.jpeg >>` without url, it does not work.

I need to return this tech.
`<< http: //my-project.loc/storage/1638956245_1.jpeg >>:`

I do not have the `Storage::url()` function working correctly.

Comment: Could you please give more context on the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs [Laravel File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls) the is expected. If you use local driver you will get the relative path from root. This means you could simply create the url based on that.

If your using S3 storage you should get the FDQN.

Comment: Will you write where I should add "filesystems ․ php"?

Comment: 'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],